# What does this CSS declaration mean?

Tags: css, declaration

could you tell me what does this declaration mean. Why does it have ul tag mentioned twice?

```
.jqueryslidemenu ul ul
```

Comment: I would like to think it is an error. I cannot seem to find a valid reason to nest an unordered list inside another.

Comment: Spaces are child selectors, not direct descendant selectors.  So you could have a li in the first ul that has a ul in it.

Comment: @Ragnar123 - No this is valid. In HTML this would become an outline with nested ULs indented to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="jqueryslidemenu">
<ul>
<ul> --> it will be for this one
```

Answer (score 7):

It would match all UL tags that are descendants of a UL Tag that is a descendant of an element that has the jqueryslidemenu class on it.

Comment: Not just children but any level of ancestor. :)

Comment: That should be "descendant".  Parent is to child as ancestor is to descendant.